# How to install/use rabbitmq-plugins on Mac

Tags: macos, rabbitmq

Installed `rabbitmq` via Homebrew

http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-standalone-mac.html

Type `rabbitmq-plugins enable amqp_client`

See an error `-bash: rabbitmq-plugins: command not found`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure your rabbitmq is running, and provide a full path to rabbitmq-plugin:

```
$ /usr/local/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable amqp_client
```